# Scipy Throwing a Tyoe Error when used inside a class

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have this three functions inside a class below

```py
    def metrics(self,*args):
        portfolio_return=np.sum(self.returns.mean()*self.weights)*252
        portfolio_volatility=np.sqrt(np.dot(self.weights.T,np.dot(self.returns.cov()*252,self.weights)))
        return np.array([portfolio_return,portfolio_volatility,portfolio_return/portfolio_volatility])

    def objective(self):
        return -self.metrics()[2]

    def optimize(self):
        optimum=optimization.minimize(fun=self.objective,x0=self.weights,args=self.returns,method='SLSQP',
        bounds=self.bounds,constraints=self.constraints)
        self.optimum = optimum
        return self.optimum
```

This throws a
`TypeError: objective() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`

I tried adding `*args` as argument to `objective`. The code runs, but unfortunately it wasn't able to get the best parameters.

Comment: `minimize` will call `fun` with `fun(x0, *args)` (see the docs).  So your function needs to run with `self.objective(self.weights, self.returns)`.  I'd suggest practicing with `minimze` with a simpler objective function that's not part of a class.  You need to understand what `minimize` does first.  I also suspect you need more practice  defining and using class methods.  It's best to tackle those two topics separately before trying to combine them.

Comment: I defined the function outside the class and it solved my issue. Is this a bad practice?

Comment: In python stand-alone functions fine.  Classes and their methods are best used to organize complex data collections that are used repeatedly.  Python provides OOP tools, but does not insist that you use them.